Do abilities work if equipped by the second CPU character?
I'm playing solo mode, so the other character is controlled by CPU and he is just following me everywhere, helping me in battles.
I can equip gears and weapons on him, and some of them have secondary skills. For example, the +20% experience.
Does this ability work if equipped by my "minion" friend and not on my active player?

Xp and gold is shared. The two characters always level up together, also when one of the characters has an xp bonus. Based on that I understand that the xp bonus is applied to the shared xp pool. So, yes, it should work.
It should work the same in singleplayer and multiplayer, as it is the same two characters.
I don't remember if there is any items with gold bonus, but I assume that would also work the same. The other stats that improve combat abilities only affect the character wearing it.
To be clear: In solo play, there is not a your character plus a minion. You can switch back and forth between the cat and the dog seamlessly. Maybe you knew that, but wanted to clarify just in case you missed it.

Good! Yeah I knew that, I meant that the CPU character is the inactive player in that moment
